# Two-man rule for sudo commands

Tags: permissions, sudo, security

I was browser popular questions on stackexchange and found this answer to a question: https://serverfault.com/a/753295/282428

What interested me was the "two-man rule", or more specifically, how to apply it to a Linux (In this case Ubuntu) system.

It was highlighted that you can't prevent a `root` user from doing anything, you can only prevent it.

So to prevent it, lets say I want each non-root user to require not only a password to run `sudo`, but the confirmation of another user on the system who also has the same restriction.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Make a long password and give each of the two "admins" half of it?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju There are not 2 users on the system,  there lets say 5. Giving each of them 5 pieces of passwords may be confusing. Also after each time it is ran, the password would have to be changed. Not feasible imho.

Comment: I know, I meant it as nearly a joke. I think `sudo` source code would have to be changed to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but might be worth considering...

Require the 5 users to use a password, as normal. However, in order to log in they also need a one-time password for [Google Authenticator's PAM module](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator) - which they'd get from a 6th user (their manager, for example). The 6th user would need to be present with them when they logged in, because OTPs only remain valid for a short time. The 6th user would also need Google Authenticator - i.e. an app on their smart phone.

I've not tried this - I've not used the Google Authenticator PAM module at all - but assuming you were happy with the "6th user" approach I see no reason why it wouldn't work. Depending on your needs (or paranoia!) you could also require a YubiKey for the 6th user.

Comment: Not exactly happy with one user having the final say on all users. But it did make me think of something. Each user has a password which will generate a temporary one-time `sudo` password for a specific user.

Doesn't answer, but brings me to an acceptable answer. Good enough.